# Twitter-Like background animated drawable in android

Tags: android, animation, background, dashboard, drawable

Just like Twitter for android used to have (they removed it) - I need to display an animated background drawable.

How to I show an image that is actually bigger then the given layout dimensions (without the image being shrink).

What kind of animation do I need to use for the "moving" effect?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should just create your own custom Drawable and handle the animation yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic, but Romain, have you any news why Twitter is not Open Source. I think the Google and Twitter team promised it... I think that would be something great for the Android dev's.